# Fediz simpleWebapp doesn't work as expected

Tags: saml-2.0, cxf-fediz

I've set up two Tomcat servers as described in the README's and the http://cxf.apache.org/ site. The tests for the IDP server work; I can see the WSDL for the web service. But when I go to https://localhost:8443/fedizhelloworld/secure/fedservlet, I just get a blank page.

The log output of the IDP server says:

```
16:56:45.379 [http-nio-9080-exec-7] DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase - Security checking request GET /fediz-idp-sts/REALMA/STSServiceTransport
16:56:45.380 [http-nio-9080-exec-7] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -   No applicable constraints defined
16:56:45.381 [http-nio-9080-exec-7] DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase -  Not subject to any constraint
```

On the RP server, I see:

```
16:58:04.941 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.FormAuthenticator - WsFedAuthenticator:invoke()
16:58:04.941 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase - Security checking request GET /fedizhelloworld/secure/fedservlet
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.FormAuthenticator - authenticate invoked
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.FormAuthenticator - reading configuration for context path: /fedizhelloworld
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] INFO  o.a.c.a.FormAuthenticator - No valid principal found in existing session. Redirecting to IDP
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - Issuer url: https://localhost:9443/fediz-idp/federation
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - WAuth: null
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - WReq: null
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - HomeRealm: null
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - Freshness: null
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - SignIn Query: null
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - wreply=https://localhost:8443/fedizhelloworld/secure/fedservlet
16:58:04.942 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - wtrealm=urn:org:apache:cxf:fediz:fedizhelloworld
16:58:04.943 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.f.c.p.FederationProcessorImpl - wctx=b6ae9556-5e4f-49ca-a9ee-493403cf1ab3
16:58:04.943 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.FormAuthenticator - Save request in session '271D4C59304744F60BDF1B84B386896C'
16:58:04.943 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase -  Failed authenticate() test
```

The README promises:

> The browser is redirected to the IDP and prompts for username and password.

but I just get a blank page with the URL `https://localhost:9443/fediz-idp/federation?wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Ffedizhelloworld%2Fsecure%2Ffedservlet&wtrealm=urn%3Aorg%3Aapache%3Acxf%3Afediz%3Afedizhelloworld&wct=2015-12-03T15%3A58%3A04.942Z&wctx=b6ae9556-5e4f-49ca-a9ee-493403cf1ab3`

My guess is that there is something wrong with the configuration but what?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both WARs (`fediz-idp.war` and `fediz-idp-sts.war`) deployed on the IDP server.

When you have, you should see this output right after `Not subject to any constraint`:

```
2015-12-04 10:19:25,030 [http-nio-9443-exec-8] INFO  org.apache.cxf.fediz.service.idp.STSPortFilter  - STSAuthenticationProvider.wsdlLocation set to https://localhost:9443/fediz-idp-sts/REALMA/STSServiceTransportUT?wsdl
2015-12-04 10:19:25,117 [http-nio-9443-exec-8] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext  - Refreshing Flow ApplicationContext [federation]: startup date [Fri Dec 04 10:19:25 CET 2015]; parent: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'idp-servlet'
2015-12-04 10:19:25,118 [http-nio-9443-exec-8] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Replacing scope 'request' from [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@447feb96] to [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@2709bb72]
2015-12-04 10:19:25,129 [http-nio-9443-exec-8] INFO  org.apache.cxf.fediz.service.idp.service.jpa.DBInitApplicationListener  - Inital DB already loaded
2015-12-04 10:19:25,131 [http-nio-9443-exec-8] INFO  org.apache.cxf.fediz.service.idp.service.jpa.DBInitApplicationListener  - Inital DB already loaded
```